# How to use hash parameter on text file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, io, initialization

I have an `initialize` method with a hash in the parameter, and need to read a file and set each key to the hash. Here's what I have so far:

```
def initialize(hash = {})
  file = file.new('filepath', 'r')
  file.each do |line|
            key, value = line.chomp.split("\n")
            options[key] = value
  end
end
```

The form of the file is:

```
AAAA "blah blah"
BBBB "blah blah"
```

I want to take `AAAA` as the key and set `"blah blah"` as the value. I've done extensive searching, but haven't found anything that resembles this issue in the same form.

EDIT:

My other issue is that the initialize method needs to receive `File.new`, so the block option for hashing won't work.

Comment: `"blah blah"` with or without quotes?

Comment: @Linuxios `AAAAA` and `"blah blah"` in 2 lines I think..

Comment: Don't assume it's two lines. The OP shows it on one line in the question's source.

Comment: @theTinMan Actually `line.chomp.split("\n")` , that `"\n"` makes me to think so.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it is on one line. The format is AAAA "blah blah" then a new line with BBBB "blah blah" and so on.

Comment: What is your expected hash tell me, then I will change me answer.

Comment: blunatic, please clear up this confusion by editing your question.  Perhaps give two sample lines from the file, with no quotes unless they are actually characters in the file, and then show the hash element(s) it produces.

Comment: hash[AAAA] = "blah blah" hash[BBBB] = "blah blah"

Comment: blunatic, don't you mean `hash['AAAA']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :options
  def initialize
    @options = {}
    File.foreach('test.txt') do |li|
      k, v = li.match(/^(\w+)\s+(.+)/).captures
      @options[k] = v
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.options # => {"AAAAA"=>"\"blah blah\"", "BBBBB"=>"\"blah blah\"", "CCCCC"=>"\"blah blah\"", "EEEEE"=>"\"blah blah\""}
```

I wouldn't pass in a hash to be populated, I'd have one defined as part of the class, then access it via a getter.

If there was a need to read from various files, then pass the name of the file to be read to the `new` method as a parameter:

```
def initialize(file)
  @options = {}
  File.foreach(file) do |li|
    k, v = li.match(/^(\w+)\s+(.+)/).captures
    @options[k] = v
  end
end
```

[`File.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is a very useful method when needing to read the lines of a file sequentially. It's very fast, and memory efficient, handling huge files just as well as small ones.

---

If you are in control of the files you're reading as preference/option files, then give serious consideration to using YAML formatted files. They're very easy to read and understand for humans, and are [usable with any language with a YAML parser](http://www.yaml.org).

The data file would look like:

```
---
AAAAA: "blah blah"
BBBBB: "blah blah"
CCCCC: "blah blah"
EEEEE: "blah blah"
```

And you'd only need to add this to your code to read it:

```
require 'yaml'

options = YAML.load_file('test.yaml')
options # => {"AAAAA"=>"blah blah", "BBBBB"=>"blah blah", "CCCCC"=>"blah blah", "EEEEE"=>"blah blah"}
```

The class code, and calling it, then becomes:

```
require 'yaml'

class Foo
  attr_reader :options
  def initialize(file)
    @options = YAML.load_file(file)
  end
end

foo = Foo.new('test.yaml')
foo.options # => {"AAAAA"=>"blah blah", "BBBBB"=>"blah blah", "CCCCC"=>"blah blah", "EEEEE"=>"blah blah"}
```

---

Here's another spin on how to go about loading the data without using a regex pattern:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :options
  def initialize(file)
    @options = Hash[File.readlines(file).map { |l| l.chomp.split(' ', 2) }]
  end
end

foo = Foo.new('test.txt')
foo.options # => {"AAAAA"=>"\"blah blah\"", "BBBBB"=>"\"blah blah\"", "CCCCC"=>"\"blah blah\"", "EEEEE"=>"\"blah blah\""}
```

This isn't as scalable as a solution using `foreach`. `readlines`, or any "read"` based solution that "slurps" the file, can cause problems if the data file grows to the point that the script's free memory is stressed.

`split` allows a parameter specifying how many values you want returned from the parsed string. In this case, a normal `split` or `split(' ')` would have returned three fields. By specifying `2` it stops splitting the string after the first space, making it easy to get the key/value pair in one call.

---

Also, if you don't want the wrapping double-quotes, you can easily strip them using something like:

```
k, v = li.tr('"', '').match(/^(\w+)\s+(.+)/).captures
```

Or:

```
k, v = li.match(/^(\w+)\s+"(.+)"/).captures
```

Or:

```
@options = Hash[File.readlines(file).map { |l| l.chomp.tr('"', '').split(' ', 2) }]
```

---

> the initialize method needs to receive File.new, so the block option for hashing won't work.

Be careful using `new`. The reason we use `open` and methods that support blocks, is to avoid leaving dangling open files behind; File will auto-close the file after the block exits. Failing to do that consumes resources and can cause programs to fail.

If you choose to ignore using blocks, ALWAYS close the file immediately after you've finished accessing it:

```
def initialize(file)
  fi = File.new(file, 'r')
  fi.each_line do |variable|
    # ...
  end
  fi.close
end
```

Or something like:

```
def initialize(file)
  fi = File.new(file, 'r')
  options = Hash[fi.readlines.map{ |l| l.chomp.split(' ', 2) }]
  fi.close
end
```

Comment: Perfect regex `/^(\w+)\s+(.+)/`.. May I use it ? :-)

Comment: The file I'm parsing here is a .conf file, so YAML isn't an option.

Comment: Then I'll toss in an even easier/shorter way to go about it.

Answer (score 2):

Write as below using the method [`IO::open`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-open):

```
def initialize(hash = {})
  File.open('filepath', 'r') do |file|
     key, value = file.readlines.map(&:strip)
     hash[key] = value
  end
end
```

Here is a full code to demonstrate this :

```
str = <<_
AAAAA "blah blah"
BBBB "blah blah" 
_

File.write('file',str)

class Foo
  def initialize(hash = {})
    File.open('file', 'r') do |file|
      file.each_line do |line|
        key, value = line.strip.split(/\s/,2)
        hash[key] = value
      end
    end
    @hash = hash
  end
  def get_hsh
    @hash
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.get_hsh # => {"AAAAA"=>"\"blah blah\"", "BBBB"=>"\"blah blah\""}
```

Comment: (Note: I'm running this against an Rspec test suite) This seemed to work. To add to this: how would I access this hash in another method further below?

Example:
def AAAA
   return hash[AAAA]
end

Comment: @blunatic: Instead of `hash` use `@hash`, and later try this: `@hash["AAAA"]`.

Comment: So this works for File.open, but my RSpec test suite wants File.new for the initialization. Could I set file = File.new(...) then run the do block on file?

Comment: [`new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-new) don't support the block.

Comment: Shoot. Then I'm back to square one.

Comment: Just put in an edit with sample of file. Sorry guys, I should've phrased my post better from get go.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually really close to getting this working: rather than splitting on "\n", you actually want to split on " ".  Also, since you only want to split once on the space (otherwise `'AAAA "blah blah"'` will become `['AAAA', '"blah', 'blah"']`), specify a limit as the second arg:

```
key, value = line.chomp.split(" ", 2)
```

As it stands at the moment, your `value` will contain the quotation marks on either side.  If you've encountered regular expressions before, you can use those:

```
def initialize(filepath, hash = {})
  File.open(filepath, 'r') do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
      if line =~ /^(?<key>\S+)\s+"(?<value>.*)"$/
        hash[Regexp.last_match[:key]] = Regexp.last_match[:value]
      end
    end
  end
end
```